# Draw rectangle using relative position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw a tree on the margin of a river using the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[{x=(1mm,0)},{y=(0,1mm)}]
%-> DEFINITIONS
%... colors
\def\rivercolor{gray!25}
\def\earthcolor{gray!50}
\def\treecolor{gray!75}

%... sizes
\def\treehgt{5}            % the height of the tree
\def\treewdt{\treehgt/4}    % the width of the tree
\def\treerad{\treehgt/4}    % the radius of the tree's cup
\def\riverwd{25}            % the width of the river
\def\riverlg{2*\riverwd}    % the length of the river

%... the tree
\def\tree#1{% #1=position
    \draw[fill=\treecolor]
        #1++(-\treewdt/2,0)--++
            (\treewdt,0)--++
            (0,\treehgt)--++
            (-\treewdt,0)--cycle
        ;
    \foreach \ang in {0,60,...,300}
        \draw[fill=\treecolor]
            {#1++(0,\treehgt+\treerad)++(\ang:\treerad)}
                circle(\treerad)
            ;
    \draw[\treecolor,fill=\treecolor]
        #1++(0,\treehgt+\treerad)
            circle(\treerad)
        ;
    }

%-> DRAW THE MARGINS
\draw[\earthcolor,fill=\earthcolor]
    (-\riverlg/5,-\riverwd/5) rectangle(\riverlg,6*\riverwd/5)
    ;
%- DRAW THE RIVER
\draw[\rivercolor,fill=\rivercolor]
    (-\riverlg/5,0) rectangle(\riverlg,\riverwd)
    ;
%-> DRAW THE TREE
\tree{(4*\riverlg/5,\riverwd)}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I would like to use a rectangle to draw its stem. I tried the following code

```
%... the tree
\def\tree#1{% #1=position
    \draw[fill=\treecolor]
        {#1++(-\treewdt/2,0)} rectangle(\treewdt,\treehgt)
        ;
    \foreach \ang in {0,60,...,300}
        \draw[fill=\treecolor]
            {#1++(0,\treehgt+\treerad)++(\ang:\treerad)}
                circle(\treerad)
            ;
    \draw[\treecolor,fill=\treecolor]
        #1++(0,\treehgt+\treerad)
            circle(\treerad)
        ;
    }
```

but it's not working.

My question is: **Why doesn't rectangle follow the relative positioning coordinates?**

Comment: I guess that these are expansion issues but since you did not bother to post an MWE, I regret to tell you that I am not willing to look at it more closely. Can you understand that it is somewhat frustrating to try to run such codes, and to realize that after adding a preamble and so on there are all sort of definitions like `\def\rivercolor{\Soft}
\def\earthcolor{\Mid}
\def\treecolor{\Dark}` which refer to unknown macros?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, @marmot. I am editing it. Please, Do `\def\Soft{gray!25}`, `\def\Mid{gray!50}` and `\def\Dark{gray!75}`. I missed these because they are defined in another file of my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using relative coordinates for the end point of the rectangle, try

```
... rectangle +(\treewdt,\treehgt)
```

Note the added `+`.